# What is the difference between declaration of a variable with "!" and without "!"?

Tags: ios, swift, declaration

I'm confused about the difference between declaration of a variable with ! and without ! ?

I know the meaning of a optional variable/constant and that ! is used to unwrapped the optional one, but I can't find any answer to answer my question.

The following declaration means a variable is declared without initialization.

```swift
var tableView: UITableView
```

But what does this declaration mean?

```swift
var tableView: UITableView!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an implicitly unwrapped optional.